Why pip list shows packages installed in venv after deactivating venv?
I am trying to lear how python venv works and it is really confusing. I am using VSCode. First, I am in a empty directory C:\Users\...\Django and when I list my libraries I get:
PS C:\Users\...\Django> pip list
Package                   Version
------------------------- ------------
altgraph                  0.17.4
bottle                    0.12.25
contourpy                 1.2.0
customtkinter             5.2.2
...

I then create venv in terminal: python.exe -m venv .venv, and I still expect to see the same installed packages because I have not activated the venv, but instead I get:
PS C:\Users\...\Django> pip list
Package Version
------- -------
pip     23.2.1

Then I activate the venv: .\.venv\Scripts\activate and I can install packages normally:
(.venv) PS C:\Users\...\Django> pip install Django
Collecting Django
...
Successfully installed Django-5.0.7 asgiref-3.8.1 sqlparse-0.5.1 tzdata-2024.1
(.venv) PS C:\Users\...\Django> pip list
Package  Version
-------- -------
asgiref  3.8.1
Django   5.0.7
pip      23.2.1
sqlparse 0.5.1
tzdata   2024.1

Now if I deactivate venv, I again expect to see all the packages that I are not in venv, but again I get:
PS C:\Users\...\Django> deactivate
PS C:\Users\...\Django> pip list
Package  Version
-------- -------
asgiref  3.8.1
Django   5.0.7
pip      23.2.1
sqlparse 0.5.1
tzdata   2024.1

Only after I deactivate and completely remove the venv, I see my packages:
(.venv) PS C:\Users\...\Django> deactivate
PS C:\Users\...\Django> rm -r *
PS C:\Users\...\Django> pip list
Package                   Version
------------------------- ------------
altgraph                  0.17.4
bottle                    0.12.25
contourpy                 1.2.0
customtkinter             5.2.2
...

But what if I want to continue my work in venv tomorrow and I would only like to deactivate it for now and then write some python code using the packages that are not installed in venv? What should I do in this kind of situation or do I need to use some other executable or something? Can someone explain what's going on?

Looks odd to me. Rather than calling activate/deactivate you could call your targets directly: i.e. .venv\Scripts\python -m pip list, this would at least rule out an activate/deactivate issue.

@cz I tried this: I created venv and I did not activate it, but when I run pip list I only get pip and no other packages. I also tried .\.venv\Scripts\python.exe -m pip list but also that gives only pip. What's going on?

You could have already activated venv and then removed and/or recreated it.
